# Correct syntax in django's forms.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, django-forms

I am currently working on forms in django, and wanted to add another field to a preexisting one in a form. The original is:

```
class NewMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['content']
```

There's another field I'd like to add, which is called 'reciever'. I was thinking maybe I'd add it like:

```
fields = ['content'], ['reciever']
```

but it gave me an error:

> File "C:\Users\Rebecca.Bi\OneDrive - St. Agnes Academy\Desktop\temp
> newsment\newsment-copy\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
> line 190, in 
> if (not exclude or f not in exclude) and f not in ignored TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

What would be the right syntax to add this new field in forms.py? I am using python 3.7

Thank you for your help - any of it counts!!

Comment: What is line 190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields = ['content'], ['reciever']` creates a tuple with 2 lists inside, which makes no sense in this context.

The error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` is due to the fact that django tries to hash every element in `fields` and lists can't be hashed.

Instead, you should just add 'reciever' to the list:

```
fields = ['content', 'reciever']
```

BTW, *reciever* should be spelled *receiver*

Comment: ah, thank you for catching the spelling error as well! This also solved my problem so yay! Edit: I can't accept your answer bc there's a time limit but I will later

Answer (score 1):

`fields` is a list with fields you've chosen, so it's that simple:

```
fields = ['content', 'reciever']
```

You can read more here: [djangoproject modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)